# Character and Digit Occurs at Least Once

Tags: regex

I wish the regex below can match the string "a34cvDrerevbf98f04389",

```
\b[0-9a-zA-Z]{21}\b
```

However, I found the regex also can match the following strings,

```
  000001111122222333334 
  #The string doesn't include a character.

  AbstractAlgebraTheory 
  #The string doesn't include a digit.
```

Does it have a way to ensure that character and digit occurs at least once in the string?

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookahead.

```
\b(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{21}\b
```

Add anchors if necessary.

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{21}$
```